# Sony Alpha USB Protocol

Tags: android, usb, sony

I try to write android apps for SONY SLT Alphas (e.g. A58). I did some reverse engineering of the USB protocol, but it is hard to find every function. Does anybody have some information about the used protocol  (Sony PTP extentions) ?
@SONY engineers: Please make the protocol public

10 00 00 00 01 00 07 92 BD 00 00 00 C7 D2 00 00

0E 00 00 00 02 00 07 92 BD 00 00 00 02 00

Comment: http://libptp.sourceforge.net/ this thing?

Comment: See documentation of libptp regarding Sony:
Please note that if your camera is supporting PTP it does not mean that it is capable of performing all PTP operations (like trigerring capture,uploading files or tweaking properties). Sony cameras are good example of poor PTP implementation where the only thing you can do is downloading files.
Sony even breaks the USB specification assigning all its cameras the same product/vendor IDs so don't buy Sony if you want to stay out of problems.